# Is it possible to build a query based on values in a String list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a table of classes already defined, but one request has been to allow selection based on categories.  Rather than creating a new table with the relevant classes categorized, I'd like to instantiate either a String or List that can be traversed to build a query.

For example, the class numbers  14891, 14898, 14899, ect are all Art-style classes.

Is it possible to do something like

```
int[] artList= {14891, 14989, 14899, .... };
```

and then build a query like

```
var query = from c in classTable where artList.contains(c.classID) select c;
```

I'm a complete newbie to ASP and complicated SQL queries as this, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you added something to your table of classes to identify the category?  Such as, say, `CategoryId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
// This is the declaration for an array:
int[] artList = new int [] {14891, 14989, 14899}; 
// And your query is just fine! Of course, you knew that, right? :)
var query = from c in classTable where artList.contains(c.classID) select c;
```

What kept you from trying, again? :)

Comment: Complete ignorance, actually. My example was based off an example distibuted by the professor.  I had no idea if it would actually work or it was a pile of cow poo!

Comment: Hehe, "pile of cow poo". Now you just gave a new name for the things produced by some of the "developers" I have met along my journey. :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Well yes:

```
var query = from c in classTable where artList.Contains(c.classID) select c;
```

would work. Some notes, that is Linq to Sql, not Sql. That query is an `IQueryable<classTable>` which hasn't actually executed yet. You wouldn't actually send the generated Sql to the database until you call an action on that query such as: `AsEnumerable(), ToList(), Max(), Count(), etc.`